# How to fix CORS error when running the React app on Android emulator?

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have developed an `Ionic React` app, running on top of `Capacitor`. In browser (ionic serve), the app runs perfectly.
When I run the app on `Android emulator` and I try to log in my App, a **CORS error** is shown.
How can I solve this error, taking in consideration that I cannot change the API server back end.
In my app I'm contacting an external API using different methods such as GET, POST and PUT.

an example of a POST Request with axios for browser:

```
    const doLogin = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {

      cardNr: cardNumber,
      name: name,
    };

    axios
    .post("/login", data)
    .then((response) => {
    //do sth
    }
    return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    });
```

** *I cannot make changed in API back-end.*

I have tried the following:

1. install `cordova-plugin-advanced-http`, according to https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/ : It requests to install`@angular/core`, but I’m working with React. Anyway, even after installing it, I cannot run the app successfully on Android, cannot login.

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

    const doLogin = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {

      cardNr: cardNumber,
      name: name,
    };

var http = new HTTP();

    http
    .post("https://xx/login", data, {})
    .then((response) => {
    //do sth
    }
    return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    });
```

2. install `@capacitor-community/http`, according to https://github.com/capacitor-community/http : in this case, when I import `‘import com.getcapacitor.plugin.http.Http’` it shows an error: `‘Cannot resolve symbol http’`.

```
import { Plugins } from "@capacitor/core";
 const doLogin = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {

      cardNr: cardNumber,
      name: name,
    };

const { Http } = Plugins;
    await Http.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://xx/login",
      data: data,
    })
    .then((response) => {
    //do sth
    }
    return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    });
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I found the solution. In this doc https://github.com/capacitor-community/http, **configuration for Android is missing**.

1- So, import and add http plugin in android\app\src\main\java\MainActivity.java

```
package com.myapp.com;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.getcapacitor.plugin.http.Http; //added

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initializes the Bridge
    this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
      // Additional plugins you've installed go here
      // Ex: add(TotallyAwesomePlugin.class);
      add(Http.class); //added
    }});
  }
}
```

2- Sync gradle files in Android Studio:

```
File --> Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

I wrote the http request according to my needs and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A fast fix could be to set the header of the post request to something which doesn't trigger a cors request, e.g. `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` .

Those requests are called "simple requests" and you can read up on them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests).

Comment: The only allowed methods for simple requests are: GET, HEAD, POST and except these, I'm using PUT request in my app too. What can I do in this case?

Comment: In this case you could add a more detailed description of your problem in your original question covering the backend you are contacting, as well as the methods which are relevant for you.

Comment: I edited my question. In the backend I cannot do nothing, I don't have permissions to change anything there. The problem is CORS error when I run my react app on Android. In Browser I have solved it using Proxy, but this is not a valid solution when I run my app on Android emulator. That's why I have tried other options such as installing http plugins, as you can read in my question.

Comment: What does the CORS header of the undisclosed api endpoint tell you?

Comment: I'm sorry, where to see this ?

Comment: In the response header you get back from the api you are requesting: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#the_http_response_headers

Comment: The headers I get in the response are: ```Date```, ```Server```, ```Content-Location```, ```Location```, ```Keep-Alive```, ```Connection```, ```Transfer-Encoding: chunked``` and ```Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8```. I don't have ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin``` in response header.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the owner of the server add Origins in allowed origins so that only those origins can call the APIs, probably your website/local URL doesn't matches with the allowed origins,

Comment: Yes it doesn't match. But what can I do if the owner of Server doesn't want to allow * Origins because of security reasons? How can I solve CORS error on Android? In the browser I solved it using proxy, but this solution is not valid for Android.

Comment: if the owner of the server don't allow then you can't request that server,